# Trying to call a function from another function with struct in it

Tags: c, function

Im having a huge problem, im trying to build some code where i call my function from another function with struct in it, however i dont know if i have confused myself, but im pretty lost right now so i would appreciate som help.
Basically what im trying to do, is to generate a random number between 1 and 4, from there i have made some if statements and in the if statements i have called my function. However, it doesnt work so well.
**Its the last piece of code that is wrong. The function "randomize()"**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DIAMONDS 0
#define CLUBS 1
#define HEARTS 2
#define SPADES 3
#define JACK 11
#define QUEEN 12
#define KING 13
#define ACE 1
#define COLOR_SIZE 13
#define NR_OF_SUITS 4
#define DECK_SIZE 52

int random_card;

struct Card
{
    int suit;
    int value;
};

void diamonds(struct Card *cardDeck);
void spades(struct Card *cardDeck);
void clubs(struct Card *cardDeck);
void hearts(struct Card *cardDeck);
void swapCards(struct Card *cardA, struct Card *cardB);
void shuffleCards(struct Card *cardDeck);
void randomize();

int main()
{

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    struct Card * deck; //Dynamiskt allokerad array

    int index;
    int suit_index;

    deck = (struct Card *)malloc(sizeof(struct Card) * DECK_SIZE);
    for (suit_index = 0; suit_index < NR_OF_SUITS; suit_index++)    /* Initiera kortleken */
        for (index = 0; index < COLOR_SIZE; index++)
        {
            deck[suit_index*COLOR_SIZE + index].suit = suit_index;
            deck[suit_index*COLOR_SIZE + index].value = index;
        }
    shuffleCards(deck);
    randomize();
    printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void swapCards(struct Card * cardA, struct Card *cardB)
{
    struct Card temp;
    temp = *cardA;
    *cardA = *cardB;
    *cardB = temp;
}

void shuffleCards(struct Card *cardDeck)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < COLOR_SIZE; i++)
        swapCards(&cardDeck[i], &cardDeck[rand() % 13]);
}

void diamonds(struct Card *cardDeck)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        switch (cardDeck[i].value + 1)
        {
        case ACE: printf("Ace ");
            break;
        case JACK: printf("Jack ");
            break;
        case QUEEN: printf("Queen");
            break;
        case KING: printf("King ");
            break;
        default: printf("%d ", cardDeck[i].value + 1);
            break;
        }
        printf("of Diamonds");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void spades(struct Card *cardDeck)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        switch (cardDeck[i].value + 1)
        {
        case ACE: printf("Ace ");
            break;
        case JACK: printf("Jack ");
            break;
        case QUEEN: printf("Queen");
            break;
        case KING: printf("King ");
            break;
        default: printf("%d ", cardDeck[i].value + 1);
            break;
        }
        printf("of spades");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void hearts(struct Card *cardDeck)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        switch (cardDeck[i].value + 1)
        {
        case ACE: printf("Ace ");
            break;
        case JACK: printf("Jack ");
            break;
        case QUEEN: printf("Queen");
            break;
        case KING: printf("King ");
            break;
        default: printf("%d ", cardDeck[i].value + 1);
            break;
        }
        printf("of hearts");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void clubs(struct Card *cardDeck)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        switch (cardDeck[i].value + 1)
        {
        case ACE: printf("Ace ");
            break;
        case JACK: printf("Jack ");
            break;
        case QUEEN: printf("Queen");
            break;
        case KING: printf("King ");
            break;
        default: printf("%d ", cardDeck[i].value + 1);
            break;
        }
        printf("of clubs");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
void randomize() {
    random_card = rand() % 4 + 1;

    if (random_card == 1) {
        struct Card c1;
        hearts(&c1);
    }
    if (random_card == 2) {
        struct Card c2;
        diamonds(&c2);
    }
    if (random_card == 3) {
        struct Card c3;
        spades(&c3);
    }
    if (random_card == 4) {
        struct Card c4;
        clubs(&c4);
    }

}
```

The output that im getting is -939213 of hearts(or the selected color). I dont know how to fix this, i have no solution at all.
Would love some help here and some solution to my problem. And FYI, i dont wanna use any global variables as u might see.

Comment: Please slim your code down to the minimum example.  Nobody is going to wade through a wall of code.

Comment: Would your ranks be better ranged from `0..12` instead of `1..13`?

Comment: Have you tried `switch`? It would make `randomize` much more clear.

Comment: Too many things wrong here... What is this `randomize()` function even supposed to do? It seems to generate random number between 1 and 4 successfully, but the purpose of the rest of the code in there is a bit baffling... Frankly, the code looks like you had a skeleton (from teacher?), and then you copyppasted some random code there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problems I see:

1. You are passing the address of a temporary `Card` to the functions `diamonds`, `spades`, etc. from `randomize`.
2. The temporary Card has not been initialized.
3. The pointer being passed to the other functions is not a deck of `Card`s. It's just a single `Card`.

Suggestion to fix the problems.

1. Pass the variable `deck` from `main` to `randomize`.
2. Pass the same variable to the other functions from `randomize`.

Change the function prototype first:

```
void randomize(struct Card* deck);
```

Change the call from `main`.

```
shuffleCards(deck);
randomize(deck);
printf("\n\n");
```

Change the implementation.

```
void randomize(struct Card* deck) {
   random_card = rand() % 4 + 1;

   if (random_card == 1) {
      hearts(deck);
   }
   if (random_card == 2) {
      diamonds(deck);
   }
   if (random_card == 3) {
      spades(deck);
   }
   if (random_card == 4) {
      clubs(deck);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i completely understand what you've written.
Appreciate this so much, thanks! Have a nice day!

Comment: @Williamhart, You are welcome. I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

The deck which you're initializing is never handed to the randomize()-function.
You're generating new Card structs on the stack and are not initializing them, thus they contain garbage.
You should pass your initialized deck to the randomize-function and use the values there, that should give you the desired behaviour.

Comment: His deck is initialized and shuffled without randomize.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `randomize` function just creates random card, and does not randomize deck.
So what you need is:

```
void randomize() {
    struct Card c;
    random_card = rand() % NR_OF_SUITS;
    c.value = rand() % COLOR_SIZE;
    switch(random_card) {
        case DIAMONDS:
            diamonds(&c);
            break;
        case CLUBS:
            clubs(&c);
            break;
        case HEARTS:
            hearts(&c);
            break;
        case SPADES:
            spades(&c);
            break;
    }
}
```

What I did is randomized value too, and rewrited it with switch and constants. And it worked like a charm.

And hey, why you are using `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)`? What is this?

But that's pretty strange to use this. Instead I'll recommend you to create function `printCard`:

```
void printCard(struct Card *cardDeck) {
    switch (cardDeck->value + 1) {
        case ACE: printf("Ace");
            break;
        case JACK: printf("Jack");
            break;
        case QUEEN: printf("Queen");
            break;
        case KING: printf("King");
            break;
        default: printf("%d", cardDeck->value + 1);
            break;
    }
    printf(" of ");
    switch (cardDeck->suit) {
        case DIAMONDS:
            printf("diamonds");
            break;
        case CLUBS:
            printf("clubs");
            break;
        case HEARTS:
            printf("hearts");
            break;
        case SPADES:
            printf("spades");
            break;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And then `randomize` function would be:

```
void randomize() {
    struct Card c;
    c.suit = rand() % NR_OF_SUITS;
    c.value = rand() % COLOR_SIZE;
    printCard(&c);
}
```

Also your code has some problems in `shuffleCards` (it would shuffle only first 13 cards), it should be:

```
void shuffleCards(struct Card *cardDeck) {
    for (int i = 0; i < DECK_SIZE; i++)
        swapCards(&cardDeck[i], &cardDeck[rand() % DECK_SIZE]);
}
```